# How to specify Lumen (or Laravel) version on new installation?

Tags: laravel, lumen

I want to install a specific version of Laravel Lumen (5.1 instead of the lastest one 5.2) on a new project.

From the documentation :

```
lumen new blog
```

or :

```
composer create-project laravel/lumen --prefer-dist
```

Does not work : it install the lastest one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install Older Version of Laravel using Composer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23043391/install-older-version-of-laravel-using-composer)

Comment: Hum ... the approach is slightly different but the original problem looks the same

Comment: I think the result is the same and googling `install specific version of laravel` its the first link. So i think its easy enough to find. That's also just one example. There is [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32042558/installing-specific-laravel-5-version-with-composer-create-project) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23754260/installing-specific-laravel-version-with-composer-create-project) too

Comment: Initially my question is for lumen, and googling with several words with lumen does not show up theses results. Thats why i created this one, but i agree, the result look the same.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Create a project using the composer command :

Create a Laravel 5.1 project into the blog folder :

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel blog "5.1.*"
```

Create a Lumen 5.1 project into the blog folder :

```
composer create-project laravel/lumen blog "5.1.*"
```

Comment: Thanks. I needed Lumen 5.2 for App Engine. :)