# How to install lumen 5.8 using Composer

Tags: laravel, composer-php, backend, lumen

My source project contains laravel/lumen 5.8 and I cloned the project recently and installed composer and when I try to install lumen in this way

```
composer global require "laravel/lumen-installer"
```

I got the latest one . How can I get Laravel/lumen 5.8 using composer or any other methods?

Comment: Check on this source. Hope it help you out! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36174497/how-to-specify-lumen-or-laravel-version-on-new-installation/36174498

Comment: so what does this command says 
`composer global require "laravel/lumen-installer" `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your app and then find composer.json and add this line:

```
"laravel/lumen-framework": "5.8.*"
```

then run

```
composer update
```

Answer (score 6):

You can create project as

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/lumen=5.8 myproject
```